# Sending back file-content instead of href with django-rest-framework?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a model for articles which takes a field `FileField` which is supposed to be a markdown file for the user to load their article already. I expose the api with a `ModelViewSet`.

This is saved to my media folder. I could fetch the content from the client side by GETing it from the `href` of course but that would mean 2 requests to my server:

1. get article info (title, content- this is the md, date published, description, etc.. ).
2. get content from the link.

But i'm wondering if there's a way to tell django to just send the content of the file instead of the `href` when it responds to a requestion for the article item.

**Here's my model and api:**

```py
# ---------------------- #
# src/articles/models.py #
# ---------------------- #

from os.path import splitext
from uuid import uuid4
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.


def hashFilename(instance, name):
    ext = splitext(name)[1]
    return "articles/{}{}".format(uuid4(), ext)


def hashImageFilename(instance, name):
    ext = splitext(name)[1]
    return "images/{}{}".format(uuid4(), ext)


class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(("title"), max_length=100)
    content = models.FileField("content", upload_to=hashFilename)
    description = models.TextField(("description"), default='')
    uploadDate = models.DateTimeField(("uploadDate"), auto_now=True)
    lastModified = models.DateTimeField(("uploadDate"), auto_now=True)
    publicationDate = models.DateField("publicationDate")
    image = models.ImageField("image", upload_to=hashImageFilename)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

```py
# ------------------------- #
# src/articles/api/views.py #
# ------------------------- #

from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet

from ..models import Article
from .serializers import ArticleSerializerFull, ArticleSerializerShort


class ArticlesViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Article.objects.all()

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.action == 'list':
            serializer = ArticleSerializerShort
        else:
            serializer = ArticleSerializerFull
        return serializer

    queryset = Article.objects.all()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Defining a [**`serializers.SerializerMethodField`**--(DRF Doc)](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) method will do the job.

```
class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    content = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_content(self, article):
        return article.content.file.read()

    class Meta:
        fields = '__all__'
        model = Article
```

---

Alternatively, you could achieve the same by overriding the **`to_representation`**  method of the serializer.

```
class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = '__all__'
        model = Article

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        rep = super().to_representation(instance)
        rep['content'] = instance.content.file.read()
        return rep
```

---

### Update-1

From [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59737609/sending-back-file-content-instead-of-href-with-django-rest-framework#comment105781470_59810784), I hope you need a ***live markdown editor in Django Admin*** rather than a ***FileField***.
So, Use [any of these markdown packages](https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/markdown/) to get a live view in the Django Admin. These packages are using [**`models.TextField`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.TextField) to store the ***markdown content***. So that you could read the content from the field in ***anywhere*** just like any other model fields

Comment: This is great. The only problem is that it doesn't leave the admin with an editing UI after having uploaded the file.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your concern. Can you explain a little bit more?

Comment: I'll break down the use-case:

My user is an admin on a website with his writings.

1. He prepares an article on his own text-editor in MD format. 2. He goes to the admin page, creates a new article, and for content uploads the MD file. 3. The front-end fetches the content well, and displays it directly on the site (after your suggested correction). 4. The user noticed an issue, he wants to update the article - currently he has to go to the file on his machine, update it, and upload it. It would be nicer if he could just edit it in the admin panel. (I understand that might be a stretch).

Comment: AFAIK, Since this content is associated with a FileField, you can't ***edit*** with a ***live view***.

Comment: Apart from that, I would like to suggest another option which is, Use [**`models.TextField(...)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.TextField) and store your markdown text.

Comment: @aviya.developer I've updated the answer. Please have a look

Comment: Alright the packages are indeed what i was looking for! Thanks!